# Creating a Discord Bot that can determine a users role in another server it is in. Unsure how to do this

Tags: discord

I am part of a nerdy online gaming group that uses Discord to communicate. We use two servers for different things, what we want to do however, is have a bot check if they are in our main server and then give them a role in the other server. I believe this is possible I just am unsure how. If someone who has experience with this could show me how to get started would be great.

*Using Node.JS*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the bot is in both servers. 
This is how you would do it:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
if (message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "Role")){
user = message.member        
const otherServer = client.guilds.get("serverID"); 
const role =server.roles.find('name', 'Role');
server.user.addRole(role);
}})
```